# Setting the position of the `ylabel`

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I am trying to recreate the look of figure below using matplotlib ([source](http://www.treesmapsandtheorems.com/pdfs/TM&Th-4.0-summary.pdf)).

[image: Template figure]

However, I am having issues with the placement of the `ylabel`. I want it at the top of the `y`-axis, as it is on the figure. I have tried setting its position with `ax.yaxis.set_label_position()`, but this only accepts `left` or `right` for the y-axis. Is there an option to control the position of the `ylabel`, or should I  just use `ax.text` and set the text's position manually?

EDIT: As it turns out, the `ax.set_ylabel(position=(x,y))` sets the position of the label relative to the graph coordinates. However, because of its horizontal rotation, the label is a little too much to the right, and `position(x,y)` does not seem to accept negative inputs. Is there a way to move the label a little to the left?

I include the code used to generate the skeleton of the figure here, even though it's rather messy.

```
import  matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r"\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}"]
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = ['serif']
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 10

nb_procs   = np.array([1,     2,        4,      12,     24,    48,     96,     192,    384])

def adjust_spines(ax, spines):
    for loc, spine in ax.spines.items():
        if loc in spines:
            spine.set_position(('outward', 10))  # outward by 10 points
            spine.set_smart_bounds(True)
        else:
            spine.set_color('none')  # don't draw spine

    # turn off ticks where there is no spine
    if 'left' in spines:
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    else:
        # no yaxis ticks
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])

    if 'bottom' in spines:
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    else:
        # no xaxis ticks
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])

# -- We create the figure.
figPres = plt.figure(figsize=(3,1.75))
axPres  = figPres.add_subplot(111)

# -- We remove any superfluous decoration.
# Remove the axis decorations on the right and on the top.
axPres.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axPres.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

# Make the remaining spines a light gray.
axPres.spines['bottom'].set_color('gray')
axPres.spines['left'].set_color('gray')

adjust_spines(axPres, ['left', 'bottom'])

# -- Set the x ticks.
axPres.set_xscale('log')
axPres.set_xlim((0.75,500))
axPres.set_xticks((nb_procs))
axPres.set_xticklabels( (r'1', r'2', r'4', r'12', r'24', r'48', r'96', r'192', r'384'), color='gray' )
axPres.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

for tic in axPres.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
  tic.tick1On = tic.tick2On = False

# -- Set the y ticks.
axPres.set_ylim((0,1))
axPres.set_yticks((0.0,0.5,1.0))
axPres.set_yticklabels((r'0', '', r'1'))
axPres.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
axPres.tick_params(axis='y', colors='gray')

#for tac in axPres.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
#  tac.tick1On = tac.tick2On = False
for toc in axPres.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
  toc.tick1On = toc.tick2On = False

# -- Set the titles of the axes.
axPres.set_ylabel(r"Efficacit\'e", color='gray', rotation='horizontal')
axPres.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
axPres.set_xlabel(r"Nombre de processeurs", color='gray')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can move the ylabel using [`ax.yaxis.set_label_coords`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_coords.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_coords), which does accept negative numbers. For your example, I removed the line with `set_label_position`, and added:

```
axPres.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1,1.02)
```

[image]

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_coords.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_label_coords):

> `Axis.set_label_coords(x, y, transform=None)`
>
> Set the coordinates of the label.
>
> By default, the x coordinate of the y label and the y coordinate of
> the x label are determined by the tick label bounding boxes, but this
> can lead to poor alignment of multiple labels if there are multiple
> axes.
>
> You can also specify the coordinate system of the label with the
> transform. If None, the default coordinate system will be the axes
> coordinate system: (0, 0) is bottom left, (0.5, 0.5) is center, etc.

For further examples of using this method, see the second example on the matplotlib [Align y-labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/align_ylabels.html#align-y-labels) example page.

Answer (score 3):

Some methods have meanwhile been deprecated. Here is a more recent approach.

I moved most of the style-options to the global style parameters.

You can find a list of available parameters with descriptions [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc).

I hope the rest is self-explanatory.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

```py
# Alternative: plt.rc_context()
plt.rcParams.update({
    'figure.constrained_layout.use': True,
    'font.size': 12,
    'axes.edgecolor': 'gray',
    'xtick.color':    'gray',
    'ytick.color':    'gray',
    'axes.labelcolor':'gray',
    'axes.spines.right':False,
    'axes.spines.top':  False,
    'xtick.direction': 'in',
    'ytick.direction': 'in',
    'xtick.major.size': 6,
    'xtick.minor.size': 4,
    'ytick.major.size': 6,
    'ytick.minor.size': 4,
    'xtick.major.pad': 15,
    'xtick.minor.pad': 15,
    'ytick.major.pad': 15,
    'ytick.minor.pad': 15,
    })
```

```py
X = np.linspace(-2,2,500)
Y = np.exp(-X**2)

# Generate Sample Points
Sx = np.random.choice(X, 31)
Sy = np.exp(-Sx**2) + np.random.normal(scale=.02, size=31)
```

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(6,4) )

# Disjoin bottom / left spines by moving them outwards
ax.spines[['bottom', 'left']].set_position(('outward', 20))

# Set axis / spine lengths
ax.spines['bottom'].set_bounds(Sx.min(), Sx.max())
ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(0, Sy.max())

ax.set_yticks( ticks=[0, Sy.max()],           labels=['0', '650 mW'])
ax.set_yticks( ticks=[(Sy.max()+Sy.min())/2], labels=[''], minor=True )

ax.set_xticks( ticks=[Sx.min(), Sx.max()], labels=['16', '19'])
ax.set_xticks( ticks=[0],                  labels=['17.2 GHz'], minor=True)

ax.set_ylabel('Output power', ha='left', y=1, rotation=0, labelpad=0)

ax.plot(X,Y, color='orange')
ax.plot(Sx, Sy, marker='o', markersize=3, linestyle='', color='black')

fig.savefig('so.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the 3.5 version of matplotlib doesn't support the `yaxis` any more. I have found a workaround that gives similar result

```py
axPres.set_ylabel(r"Efficacit\'e", loc="top", rotation="horizontal")
```

Comment: _"3.5 version of matplotlib doesn't support the `yaxis` any more"_ Not sure what you mean. This still works fine in version 3.5.1: `axPres.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1, 1.02)`