# matplotlib set ylabel padding to zero

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have a plot

[image: Default padding]

and I want to move the ylabel closer to the Y axis. I achieve this by `axes.set_ylabel('neuron', labelpad=-20)` but `-20` padding is, of course, arbitrary and I want to have a general solution rather than hardcoding the value there. It's guaranteed that ylabelticks do not intersect with the ylabel.

[image: No padding]

Comment: Does [Setting the position of the `ylabel` in a matplotlib graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815976/setting-the-position-of-the-ylabel-in-a-matplotlib-graph) answer your question?

Comment: `axes.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1,1.02)` is also arbitrary and not better than `axes.set_ylabel('neuron', labelpad=-20)` IMHO

Comment: [https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#axis-label](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#axis-label)

Comment: A generalized solution as in - getting the dimensions of the label then ensuring that its closest edge is x units away from the yaxis?

Comment: @wwii sorry, you're right! I should use `axes.yaxis.set_label_coords(0.0, 0.5)`. I voted to close it as a duplicate.